# Aliasing of the oscillations of a one-dimensional harmonic chain

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I am reading chapter 9 of the Oxford Solid State Basics and in this chapter, the author considers a chain of masses connected to each other via springs of constant $\kappa$. He solves the problem by means of an attempted solution of the form

\begin{equation}
\delta x_{n} = A\,e^{i(\omega t-kna)}
\end{equation}

where $\delta x_{n}$ is the displacement of the $n$th mass from its equilibrium position at $na$ and $a$ is the lattice constant of the chain.

Now, this solution doesn't change for $k\rightarrow k+2\pi/a$, which raises the question that "if this is the case, and the position of the $n$th mass is the same in both cases how should we choose $k$?"

Associated to this question comes questions like "how should we interpret the phase velocity $v_{phase}=\omega/k$ if $k$ and $k+2\pi/a$ are the same?"

The author's answer to these questions is:

*The resolution of this puzzle is to realize that $k$ and $k+2\pi/a$ are only equivalent so long as one only measures the wave at lattice points $x_{n} = na$ and not ar arbitrary points $x$ along the axis.*

He then refers to the following picture:

[image]

A few points about this:

1) Maybe this picture is a bit misleading because the only variable in the solution is $t$. This is not the oscillation of a field that propagates in space, but rather the oscillation of a position in space. So if each black dot represents a mass, the x-axis is their position in the lattice and the y-axis is their distance from their equilibrium position. And the picture is a representation of such positions for a given time $t$.

From this perspective then we cannot tell both waves apart because we are only allowed to look at the positions 1a, 2a, 3a... and so forth, and the speed such points go up and down is the same for both cases. The problem is, however, the author mentions that all this only makes sense if we measure the wave at lattice positions, but the oscillation of each mass happens around these lattice points. How can you measure the amplitude of this oscillation if you are only allowed to look at the equilibrium position?

This picture shifts the motion that should be horizontal into a vertical motion so we can better appreciate the wave-like nature of such displacements through the whole lattice, but if we put it back into its horizontal position and then only look at positions $x_{n}=na$, then we will only measure the period, by having a beep every time the mass $n$ is at the point $x=na$

2) The motivation for the question about how should we choose $k$ was the wavelength definition: $\lambda=2\pi/k$, which we can see the effect of in the picture. The wavelength is the distance in space between two consecutive maxima (or minima) of a signal, right? Again, this is valid for a wave propagating in space, but which is an oscillation of some field. In the case of a mass oscillating around an equilibrium position, the closest we get to a wavelength is 2$A$, the distance between maximum displacements to each side of the equilibrium position. So k is not connected to these maxima in this case because the oscillation is happening in time. By this, I mean that, if you look at an electromagnetic field, at any given time at a position $x$ you can get a reading. For the oscillating masses, however the mass is not at all times in a given position. The position itself is what is changing with time.

So, if for this case the wavelength is not associated with $k$, why does it even matter which $k$ we pick? And if the oscillation is not propagating in space, what is the sense of the wave momentum $\hbar k$?

I apologise if these questions are too simple. I got trapped thinking about it and would appreciate some fresh insights on it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not focus on a single mass.

A single mass is just an oscillator, while here we consider the whole chain and the waves that propagate through this chain (waves are just oscillations that propagate in space).

All the masses oscillate with the same period, but if we look at the chain at fixed time the masses will be in different phases of this oscillation.

If I start from one mass, the wavelength can be seen as the distance after which I find another mass which is oscillating with the same phase.

In this context $k$ is the momentum associated with the wave not with the oscillation of a single mass.

### Some more notes

The textbook implicitly assumes that you can follow the motion of just the masses: this means that you can **sample** the system with a sampling length equal to the distance between the masses, i.e. $l_s = a$. A significant result of Fourier analysis tells us that the representation of the system in the momentum space will be periodic with period $2\pi / l_s = 2\pi / a$. 
Therefore, all signals which have the same representation in the momentum domain (same spectrum) apart that they are separated by an integer multiple of the period  $2\pi / a$ are practically indistinguishable.

All of this will become clear when you study Fourier analysis and the [sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem).

**Care:** usually these topics are treated in the time and frequency domains, but the same ideas apply if you consider space and wave vector domains and in general for all *conjugate* quantities.

Comment: This was incredibly insightful. Thank you very much.

Comment: @NeonGabu Happy to help! If you have further questions, let me know.